# Using custom JAXB context with Jersey client

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey client 1.8 + JAXB. I want to post a JSON payload that looks like the following:

```
{
    "transactions": [ 
    {
        "amount":
        {
            "currency":"EUR","total":"1"
        }
        ...
    }
    ],
}
```

I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PaymentRequestDTO
{
    @XmlElement(name="transactions")
    public List<TransactionDTO> getTransactions()
    {
        return transactions;
    }
}
```

When the list contains only one transaction though what I post is:

```
{
    "transactions": {
        "amount":
        {
            "currency":"EUR","total":"1"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Transactions are not treated as array... I've lost couple of hours to research this issue incl. lots of searching in SO and I've read that I have to register my own context resolver -> [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section).

So here it is:

```
@Provider
public class XXXJAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext>
{
    private JAXBContext context;

    private Class<?>[] types = { PaymentRequestDTO.class, TransactionDTO.class, AmountDTO.class };

    public XXXJAXBContextResolver() throws Exception
    {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), types);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType)
    {
        for (Class<?> type : types)
        {
            if (type == objectType)
            {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The registration itself:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(XXXJAXBContextResolver.class);
client = Client.create(cc);
```

I've used the so called natural notation:

> The natural JSON notation, leveraging closely-coupled JAXB RI
>   integration.
>
> Example JSON expression:
>
> {"columns":[{"id":"userid","label":"UserID"},{"id":"name","label":"User
>   Name"}],"rows":[{"userid":1621,"name":"Grotefend"}]}

[Link](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONConfiguration.Notation.html#NATURAL).

Still the same result - no array in the payload. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information:

I've activated the POJO mapping (means that jackson is used underneath) and the JSON generated is what I need...... hmmm...

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
```